# Django not responding when i change DataBase to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql-10

i changed the Django database to postgresql and when i command runserver or migrate or makemigrations, django wont response.

also no error occurs

im using Django 5 and PostgreSQL 10

i tried restarting the postgres server and making new projects but still stays that way

Comment: Django 5.0 does not support PostgreSQL 10.  Look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes).  You need PostgreSQL 12 andf above.